# 'TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT' of undefined pdfmake

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, pdfmake

I am working with angular 1.5 with webpack. And I want to create PDF with pdfmake for that I am including two js in

```
import '../../../vendor/js/pdfmake.min.js';
import '../../../vendor/js/vfs_fonts.js';
```

but after including when I run application with gulp serve command it didn't shown any error on console but on browsers developer console it displays error

```
Cannot read property 'TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT' of undefined
```

The Line in pdfmake.js where I have an error is

```
 t.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT = void 0 !== r.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT ? r.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT : i(), t.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT && (t.prototype.__proto__ = Uint8Array.prototype, t.__proto__ = Uint8Array), t.isBuffer = function(t) {
```

Comment: have you found a solution?